# Create/Modify new WPF UI components

Tags: wpf, user-interface, element

I want to change the graphical UI elements in WPF.
For example, I want to use a kind of a stack panel, but on the other hand I want to show my details in a star, or circle, etc.

Maybe setting a bitmap as a background, but I am working with lots of Data using zoom tool.

I found tutorials, documentation only for changing attributes of "old components", but nothing to make new ones.

Comment: You should probably read the [Archive for the ‘Control Templates’ Category](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/control-templates/) page on the Dr WPF website. However, you can't provide a `ControlTemplate` for a `StackPanel` because it is not a `Control`, but you can just put a shape in the background and hide the `StackPanel Background`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great resource for WPF beginners is [www.wpftutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net)

One of the best idea of WPF is separation of concerns:

> UI Control = Logic in Code/XAML + Template

Using templates in XAML we can vary representation without modifying the control.

For example, if there is a need in creation of list of items. Then we can use [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>USA</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>UK</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

By default `LisboxItem` internal part is just binded `TextBlock`.

Now making UI modification without changing control source code:

```
<ListBox ImageSource="{Binding PathToSource}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{StaticResource ProjectIcon}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

there appears image and text.

If there is a need in creating exclusive control then you can always use [Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx).

---

Using raster images (e.g. PNG) is not good point, especially with zoom behaviour. If it is possible better to use vector images, that can be created in XAML or imported from SVG.

Comment: Now I have time to check it. I accept it as an answer ^^, also I think I found a solution for the zooming, I can set a Bitmap as a rendered image, when the user wants to use zoom.